# How to exactly use (negated) character classes or scansets while using sscanf on a string?

Tags: c, scanf

I have multiple rows of strings and I want to store it in the form:

```
string1   string2   float1   float2   float3   float4   float5   float6
```

as in the conversion specifiers mentioned below.  For example:

```
Kevlar ABS 43.42 13.94 1.35 0.35 0.112 2.74
```

Two strings are Kevlar and ABS, the remaining 6 are numbers. There are white space characters between all 8 of them.

I am wondering how I can use scansets or (negated) character classes only to store the required information in all the 8 conversion specifiers.

The struct is declared as follows:

```
 struct lamina
 {
    char lamina_fiber[30];
    char lamina_matrix[30];
    float E1,E2,p,v12,v21,G12;
    struct lamina *nextnode;
 };


 head=(struct lamina *)calloc(1,sizeof(struct lamina));
 current=head;

 for(int i=1;i<=index_elements;i++)
 {
     sscanf(rows[i],"%s %s %f %f %f %f %f %f", 
            current->lamina_fiber,current->lamina_matrix,&current->E1, 
            &current->E2,&current->p,&current->v12,&current->v21, 
            &current->G12);
     current->nextnode=(struct lamina *)calloc(1,sizeof(struct lamina));
     current=current->nextnode;
 }

 current=head;

 for(int i=1;i<=index_elements;i++)
 {
       printf("%s %s %f %f %f %f %f %f", current->lamina_fiber, current->lamina_matrix,
              current->E1, current->E2,current->p, current->v12,  
              current->v21, current->G12);
       current=current->nextnode;
 }
```

---

NB: Version 1 of the code in the question contained:

```
if(n=(sscanf(rows[i],"%s %s %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f", 
current->lamina_fiber,current->lamina_matrix,&current->E1, 
&current->E2,&current->p,&current->v12,&current->v21,&current->G12))!=8);
```

This explains the reference to `if` and a trailing semicolon in the answer.

Comment: Please do not edit a question so as to invalidate answers once they are given.

Comment: Your code should read the 'Kevlar' data.  You need to show how your structure is defined.  If you have `char *lamina_fiber` instead of a `char` array, you've got problems, for example.  You should test the return value from `sscanf()`; if it is not 8, you have problems.  You should print out the string you are parsing (one of the _major_ benefits of using `sscanf()` is that you _can_ report the string that was being parsed; you can't do that with plain `scanf()`!).  You should report how many values were converted (the return value from `sscanf()`); you might print the strings it read.

Comment: Your original code used `%5.2f` — that's not a valid [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) conversion specification.  You can't use the `.2` notation.  You can only specify a maximum width to convert.  That would account for the `sscanf()` failing on the numbers.  Even if you could use it, the `0.112` value would cause confusion.

Comment: I have added how I have defined my struct.

Comment: @AMD: Thanks — that structure definition is safe enough.  Strictly, you should use `%29s` in the `sscanf()` format string to limit the input strings, but that's a commonly overlooked refinement (even though it is important in production programs for security reasons — can you say [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)).

Answer (score 1):

The conditional statements have two problems. The condition you have,

```
n=(sscanf(rows[i],"%s %s %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f", 
  current->lamina_fiber,current->lamina_matrix,&current->E1, 
  &current->E2,&current->p,&current->v12,&current->v21,&current->G12))!=8
```

may look like it assigns the return value of `sscanf` (which should be 8) to `n`, and then checks whether that was 8 as it should be. But in fact it does something else: it assigns to `n` the result of the condition

```
(sscanf(rows[i],"%s %s %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f", 
  current->lamina_fiber,current->lamina_matrix,&current->E1, 
  &current->E2,&current->p,&current->v12,&current->v21,&current->G12))!=8
```

which should be `true`, or since `n` is an integer, 1.

The next problem is that your `if` condition ends with a `;` so there isn't anything that gets done or not depending in it; your program just continues with the next two statements: first printing

> Problem!n=1

and then printing the original input string, `rows[1]`.

Comment: @AMD you have only one `printf` statement which prints the whole line which you read with `fgets`. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input *in the question*. Nobody can replicate the problem as posted, and it is unclear exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @AMD The suggestion of Weather Vane is a good one. As it is, the `printf("%s\n",rows[i])` command prints `rows[i]`, which is the *raw input*, not the result of `sscanf`.

Comment: @AMD As you have edited the code in your question, does it work correctly now?

Comment: @ Jim Danner: No it is not working correctly

Comment: @ Weather Vane: I am sorry regarding the previous code, please disregard the if and the printf statements from the previous code. I believe the code posted as of now can be considered minimal, complete and verifiable?

Comment: @AMD: did you remember that arrays are indexed from 0?  Your loop starts at 1.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler: I am trying to skip the first row because it contains headings for every column and does not include the input. Therefore, I am trying to start from 1.

Comment: @AMD the ideal [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) can be copy/pasted and compiled to replicate the problem. BTW please omit spaces from user names if you want to flag a commenter.